# Nuxt modern application build stops on 95% and does not end up

Tags: javascript, build, nuxt.js

I have a Nuxt application which sometimes does not end the build correctly. It stops on 95% and does not end up the process. What could be the problem?

Look at the screenshot

[image]

Comment: You do have an error tho? Did you tried fixing the `export 'default'` one?

Comment: Its warning. Not error and in most cases it works regardless that warning.

Comment: I mean, if you're looking to have a working project, fixing even the warnings is not a bad start, especially when you can leverage those parts yourself.

Comment: This is insane. It thorws a lot of warnings all the time. Also the fatal error is if I forget to add space after the comment. It is like a nightmare.

Comment: Maybe try to fix the ESlint issues, it's actually here to help you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are setting a wrong path when you are exporting the UtilsBuefyHelper.

Comment: It is warning. it should not break the build.

Comment: @Čamo fixing all the possible errors is (still) always the better solution anyway!